# simplify the following logarithm and roots expression

Tags: logarithms

please , I need help to solve this problem
Can anyone solve it
 simplify the following

$\log{\sqrt[4]{729\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{39}\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{1}{27}\right)^4}}}}$

thank in advance to all

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: HINT:  $729 = 3^6$ and $27 = 3^3$

Comment: Hmmm ... where's the logarithm?

Comment: Use $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$

Comment: Make sure you wrote down the fraction ${3}\over{9}$ correctly

Comment: sorry logarithm is first thing @john

Comment: thanks for all but i forget the log in the first of problem and there is no 3\9 it 39

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/34867/madrit-zhaku
thank you

Comment: @egreg where is your edit

Comment: @SaddamEscap Please, check now if it's correct

Comment: @egreg ok i will do thanks

Comment: @Nika I think this is correct answer

Comment: @SaddamEscap Are you done with your problem? My answer would be -${1}\over{4}$ $\log39$

Comment: @egreg you are the best
but it is 39 not 1\39 and it \sqrt(1\(1\27)^4)

Comment: @SaddamEscap Though if it is 39 instead of the ${1}\over{39}$ then forget about the minus sign in front of the fraction. Best of luck!

Comment: @Nika thanks i understood that

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps:

1. $\left(\dfrac{1}{27}\right)^4=3^{-12}$ with square root $3^{-6}$
2. $\frac{1}{39}=3^{-1}\cdot 13^{-1}$
3. $\sqrt[3]{3^{-7}\cdot 13^{-1}}=\left(3^{-7}\cdot 13^{-1}\right)^{1/3}$
4. $729=3^6=\left(3^{18}\right)^{1/3}$
5. $\sqrt[4]{\left(3^{11}\cdot 13^{-1}\right)^{1/3}}=\left(3^{11}\cdot 13^{-1}\right)^{1/12}$
6. $\log\left(\left(3^{11}\cdot 13^{-1}\right)^{1/12}\right)=\dfrac{11\log(3)-\log(13)}{12}$

something like that...

Sad thing that I do not trust my own calculations any more than this, but in order to confirm this we have [A Wolfram Alpha Computation confirming this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28%28729%2a%281%2F39%2asqrt%28%281%2F27%29%5E4%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29%5E%281%2F4%29%29)

Comment: Sorry, but I think you should check again your solution

Comment: Now your solution is correct

Comment: @MadritZhaku: Thanks!